# Full width responsive div showing two images

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to have a large image always be centered and as wide as the screen/browser window.

I pretty much have it working but there is a smaller version of the image rendering right now:

[image]

The image on the right is showing full screen regardless of zoom or window size. The one on the left should not b

```css
.wrapper{
 background: url('http://trendpie.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/4843-8.jpg') no-repeat   center center fixed;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
    <header>
      <div class="wrapper">
          <img src="http://trendpie.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/4843-8.jpg" alt="Responsive image">
      </div>
    </header>
```

I realize that the image source is being defined in two places but if I remove it from the HTML I get the following result:

[image]

Comment: if you remove the img tag src so it's just `img src=""` what happens ? what's the css for `.img-responsive`

Comment: making it just 'img src=""' has the same result as removing it which is shown in the 2nd picture. I'll post what .img responsives does above.

Comment: Actually, removing that class all together makes it function the same way.

Comment: what happens if you remove just the css background image, does that feck the site aswell ?

Comment: what about adding `style="display:none;"` direct on the image tag ?

Comment: display:none makes the image not show at all. The page starts at the next 'hello world' div. And yes, removing it in the css makes only the right image show not the left which is the one I actually want to show.

Comment: style="visibility:hidden;" works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inline image is currently setting the height of the wrapper and stopping it from collapsing. If you set the height explicitly (or using something like padding-top) you can get the desired result without needing to declare both.

```css
.wrapper{
 background: url('http://trendpie.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/4843-8.jpg') no-repeat   center center fixed;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
  
    height: 500px; /* or something like padding-top: 60% if you want a responsive ratiobox */
}
```

```html
<header>
      <div class="wrapper" role="img" aria-label="Banner Image"></div>
</header>
```